# Java in Windows: files in a directory ordered with a specific name

Tags: java, windows, date, filesystems, filenames

I'm writing a Java program which, during the execution, creates a log file named with this format:

```
dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH_mm_ss_dd_MM_yy");
```

After the execution of the program I obtain in a specific directory the file named like this:

14_10_02_17_07_19.log

because the file was automatically created during the execution at 14:10:02 on 17/07/2019.
After some executions, I'll have some files in this directory and each name of them is obviously different.
I need to store log files in DESCENDING order from the most recent(first) to the oldest(last).

How can I do it using this format ("HH_mm_ss_dd_MM_yy") or similar for the file name?
Is there a way to do this without manually modifying the directory properties and not using the last modified date of file?

Comment: Why don't you use the format: `yy_MM_dd_HH_mm_ss`? Then you'll only need to sort alphabetically.

Comment: I'd do exactly the same kind of thing Oscar Perez advise you. Because sometimes you have to adapt to how your computer works.
How do you use your files? Directly from the file explorer? Then that's the way to go. I name all my files accordingly so that they display in order.
Otherwise you'd need a program to read the list of log files and sort them as you wish with your own criteria.

Comment: That's (one of) the purpose(s) of a standard format, like `ISO_DATE` (`"yyyy-MM-dd"`), it is sortable alphabetically.

Answer (score 0):

Files in a Windows directory do not have a stored order. Windows Explorer sorts files alphabetically by default.

Surely sorting by last modified date works for your purposes?

If your question is how to sort in this way in Java, `Arrays.sort()` provides you with this functionality. For example, `Arrays.sort(list, new WindowsExplorerStringComparator());` will sort it in the same way as Windows Explorer.

However, since files do not have an explicit order, there is no way so save the files in a special way so that Windows Explorer always loads them in a specific order, without a hacky solution like putting a prefix on the filename to force a particular alphabetic ordering.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason why you can't name your log files whatever you like within the rules of the specific Operating System. There is also no guarantee that the files will be saved in a specific directory in any particular order. The order in which you want to visually view the files is up to your application displaying those created files.

For displaying files in creation Ascending or Descending order, I think the creation (or last modified) timestamp of the file is the best alternative to sort by rather than the file name itself. A timestamp within the file name merely provides a quick reference to the desired file to view which of course makes total sense and should therefore be used but... for sorting for display purposes from newest file to oldest file OR oldest file to newest file should be done by the timestamp of each file. This only makes sense as well.

Below I provide a method (**getFolderFilesInOrder()**) for doing exactly what is stated above. The method sorts the files in a supplied directory (folder) via the creation (last modified) timestamp in Ascending OR Descending order. By default the method will return a String[] Array of all the files within the specified directory in Ascending order. If **1** is supplied to the **sortOrderType** parameter then the method will return a String[] Array of all the files within the specified directory in Descending order.

Here is the **getFolderFilesInOrder()** method (Java 8+):

```
/**
 * Returns a String[] Array of all the files within the supplied directory (folder) 
 * in either Ascending or Descending order. By default the full absolute path and 
 * the file name are returned, not just the file name.<br><br>
 * 
 * If you want the files list to be sorted in Descending Order the supply <b>1</b> 
 * within the optional <b>sortOrder</b> parameter.<br><br>
 * 
 * If you want just the file names within the String[] Array then supply <b>1</b> 
 * within the optional <b>fileNamesOnly</b> parameter.<br><br>
 * 
 * @param folderPath (String) The full path to the file system directory (folder) 
 * in which you want to get the list of files from.<br>
 * 
 * @param options (Optional - Integer):<pre>
 * 
 *      sortOrder       - Default is 0 (Ascending Order) which means the files
 *                        list will ne returned in ascending sort order. If any 
 *                        value other than 0 (ie: 1) is supplied then the files
 *                        list will be returned in descending order.
 * 
 *      fileNamesOnly   - Default is 0 where Path and file name are returned within
 *                        the String[] Array. If any value other than 0 (ie: 1) 
 *                        is supplied then only the file names itself will be 
 *                        returned within the String[] Array.
 *                     
 *                        If an argument is supplied to this optional parameter 
 *                        then something MUST also be supplied to the optional 
 *                        <b>sortOrder</b> parameter (either 0 or 1).</pre>
 * 
 * @return (One Dimensional String Array) The files contained within the supplied 
 * directory path in the desired sort order based on their Creation (or last modified) 
 * timestamp.
 */
public String[] getFolderFilesInOrder(String folderPath, int... options) {
    File folder = new File(folderPath);
    if (!folder.exists() && !folder.isDirectory()) {
        System.err.println("Either the supplied folder doesn't exist "
                         + "or it is not a directory!");
        return null;
    }
    int sortOrder = 0;      // Default - Ascending Order | any value other than 0 for Descending Order.
    int fileNamesOnly = 0;  // Default - Path & file name | any value other than 0 for file names only.
    if (options.length >= 1) {
        sortOrder = options[0];
        if (options.length >= 2) {
            fileNamesOnly = options[1];
        }
    }

    File[] folderFilesList = folder.listFiles();
    if (sortOrder == 0) {
        Arrays.sort(folderFilesList, Comparator.comparingLong(File::lastModified));
    } 
    else {
        Arrays.sort(folderFilesList, Comparator.comparingLong(File::lastModified).reversed());
    }

    List<String> filesList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (File f : folderFilesList) {
        if (f.isFile()) {
            filesList.add(fileNamesOnly == 0 ? f.getAbsolutePath() : f.getName());
        }
    }
    return filesList.toArray(new String[0]);
}
```

To use this method:

```
String folderPath = "C:\\My Log File\\AppLogs";
String[] logFiles = getFolderFilesInOrder(folderPath);
for (String s : logFiles) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

A String[] array named logFiles will contain all the log files (*with paths*) found within the `C:\\My Log File\\AppLogs` directory in **Ascending** order based on files timestamp.

---

```
String[] logFiles = getFolderFilesInOrder(folderPath, 1);
```

A String[] array named logFiles will contain all the log files (*with paths*) found within the `C:\\My Log File\\AppLogs` directory in **Descending** order based on files timestamp.

---

```
String[] logFiles = getFolderFilesInOrder(folderPath, 0, 1);
```

A String[] array named logFiles will contain all the log files (*file names only*) found within the `C:\\My Log File\\AppLogs` directory in **Ascending** order based on files timestamp.

---

```
String[] logFiles = getFolderFilesInOrder(folderPath, 1, 1);
```

A String[] array named logFiles will contain all the log files (*file names only*) found within the `C:\\My Log File\\AppLogs` directory in **Descending** order based on files timestamp.